# Passing structures as arguments in Rust

Tags: struct, rust, reference, ownership

I am building a graphics engine from scratch in Rust.
I have a struct Point:

```
struct Point {
  x: i32,
  y: i32
}
```

and a triangle struct, which is just three points:

```
struct Triangle (Point,Point,Point)
```

.

I made a trait Engine that I will later implement with SDL

```
trait Engine {
  fn draw_triangle(&self,tri:Triangle){
     self.draw_line(tri.0,tri.1);
     self.draw_line(tri.1,tri.2); // <-
     self.draw_line(tri.2,tri.0);
  }
  fn draw_line(&self,p1:Point,p2:Point)

}
```

I get an error on line with an arrow: use of moved value tri.1, value used after move.
I know this has something to do with references and ownership, and have experimented changing things, but I just don't know what I am doing.
I have searched and searched, but to no avail: I cannot comprehend.

Can anyone tell me why this is not working? More than a solution, I wish to understand

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you read a book on Rust, such as the official book, or O'Reilly's "Programming Rust"? Both do a decent job of explaining the concept of _moving_ sufficiently for you to understand the solution (as is your wish). The solution is to add `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` above the definition of `struct Point`. It will make `Point` behave more like a very simple primitive object (like a number or bool), allowing it to be passed to function by copy instead of by move.

Answer (score 2):

On the first `draw_line` call, you pass two points `tri.0` and `tri.1`. This "moves" the variables into the `draw_line` function, and they cannot be used afterwards. There are two ways to get around doing this.

Firstly, you can copy (or clone) the points when calling the functions by simply adding `#[derive(Clone, Copy)]` above the `struct Point` line. This allows Points to be either cloned explicitly (by using the `.clone()` method) or copied implicitly. This means that the data will be copied every time you pass it into a function, which in this case isn't a big deal. However, for larger structs, this will want to be avoided and as such you can use the following method.

Secondly, you can pass the Points as a reference instead of by value. This can be accomplished by changing the `draw_line` signature to accept a Point reference as follows:

```rust
fn draw_line(&self, p1: &Point, p2: &Point);
```

However, this means you now also need to pass the Points by reference, leading to the following trait definition:

```rust
trait Engine {
    fn draw_triangle(&self, tri: Triangle) {
        self.draw_line(&tri.0, &tri.1);
        self.draw_line(&tri.1, &tri.2);
        self.draw_line(&tri.2, &tri.0);
    }

    fn draw_line(&self, p1: &Point, p2: &Point);
}
```

This leads to the Points themselves not being passed into the function, but instead a reference to a single Point - meaning the structs don't need to be copied six times (two for each function call). If this method was called a lot, or the structs were larger, this could be a significant speedup.

The following chapter of the rust book provides a thorough explanation of ownership, references, and borrowing: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-00-understanding-ownership.html.